# Routing between two NICs

Tags: routing, mac-osx

This question is similar to a question I asked regarding linux servers, but I am making a separate post as this question regards setting up the NICs on a Macintosh running 10.13.4 (the latest Mac OS X release).

The powers that be have decided that fixed network addresses cannot access the internet through the firewall, but that DHCP addresses can. Putting aside the somewhat dubious logic of this decision, I have decided to try and optimize my computers to make the best of this situations. The iMac Pro in question has two NICs, one a WiFi NIC, and the other a gigabit hardware ethernet NIC. The local network has the form xxx.xxx.0.0/16 while the "internet" is everything else. I wish to be to access the internet via the DHCP port, but direct all traffic addressed to machines on the local area network via the fixed hardwired ethernet port. There is a slight complication in that the DHCP address will have the same form as the fixed address, e.g. it will be allocated an address of the form xxx.xxx.yyy.yyy where the yyy bits are decided by the DHCP server. I would be grateful for suggestions as to how to set up the routing to achieve this. Note that both NICs are on the same network.

At the moment, I have made an attempt to solve this by setting up the hardwired connection to have the highest priority (in the control panel) with the WiFi connection having the second priority. I have removed the routing field from the hardwired connection configuration. I assume this will force all connections that are addressed to destinations outside of my ethernet zone to be directed to the WiFi port. Is this correct? Better yet, is there a more intelligent way to do achieve the same goals, perhaps with setting up paths for the routed? Thanks for any advice in advance.